# Why is the message filtering not working on promoted properties

Tags: filter, expression, biztalk

I have an orchestration in Biztalk 2020 with WCF-SQL receive port. The receive message in the orchestration should use filter expression to only start the orchestration if the value is new. This works fine when I add a filter expression using BST.MessageType or no filter expression on the receive message. But as soon as I add a filter expression using the promoted property, I get a routing failure.

Here is the promoted property in the schema.
[image]

Here is the filter expression on the receive message.
[image]

And Last is the Property Schema.
[image]

Failed message Context pictures below
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Additional information added

Comment: Have a look at the context properties that are on the suspended message & routing failure report, and include those here.  Where do you expect the message to go if it doesn't have the CurrentControlStatus set to NEW?

Comment: I have several orchestration being kicked off depending on the value in the field. This is just a project to see why the message is not being picked up by current orchestrations.  I have added the context from the failed message.

Comment: Well, unless I'm going blind, that Promoted Property, CurrentControlStatus, is not in the Context Properties, so you need to work out why.  Do you have a XML disassembler on the Receive Location?

Comment: I have noticed that since you asked for the context. But it just gone. I have tried to promote using a custom pipeline, but no pleasure going down that root. So far I have had no success at finding the reason on why the promoted properties are missing from the context.

Comment: Are all the nodes above that promoted property occurs 1?  You can't have a promoted property on something that occurs multiple times.  Did you add the promoted property later, if so did you restart the host instances after re-deploying?

Comment: Also you didn't answer "Do you have a XML disassembler in the Pipeline on the Receive Location"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several different issues

1. You added the promoted property later, and either haven't deployed it fully, or have not restarted the host instance since you deployed it.  Which means the host instance might still have loaded in memory and older version of the schema without the promoted property.  **Fix**: Make sure you have rebuilt your solution in Visual Studio, have deployed your solution and have restarted the host instances after the deployment.
2. You don't have XML disassembler component in the Receive Location Pipeline.  Even if you are already getting XML, you need to have this component in your pipeline as one of the things it does is to do the Property Promotion. **Fix**: Have a XML disassembler component in the Receive Location Pipeline.
3. The namespace in the XML does not match that of the schema.  Fix: Either have the namespace created at the source, or add a pipeline component to add/replace the namespace.

Comment: I found the problem, although the xml produced by the sql script had the correct structure it had no namespaces in it. I updated the sql script to produce the xml with namespaces and the message was correctly consumed with the promotion of the required fields.

Comment: @Ivan  Yes, that would do it as well.  I've added that is a reason to my answer